# Spring Data JPA: Query by Example?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Using Spring Data JPA can I do a [query by example](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-examples) where a particular entity instance is used as the search criteria?

For example (no pun intended), if I have a `Person` entity that looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private boolean employed;
  private LocalDate dob;
  ...
}
```

I could find all employed persons with a last name of Smith born on January 1, 1977 with an example:

```
Person example = new Person();
example.setEmployed(true);
example.setLastName("Smith");
example.setDob(LocalDate.of(1977, Month.JANUARY, 1));
List<Person> foundPersons = personRepository.findByExample(example);
```

Comment: Your questions is not clear. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: No you cannot as that is limited to hibernate, Spring Data is designed for JPA. You can always create a `Specification` and execute that which you could then use to do something similar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Spring data relies on top of JPA and EntityManager, not Hibernate and Session, and as such you do not have findByExample out of the box. You can use the spring data automatic query creation and write a method in your repository with the following signature:

```
List<Person> findByEmployedAndLastNameAndDob(boolean employed, String lastName, LocalDate dob);
```

Comment: JPA != Hibernate.  Makes sense.  I think going the `Specification` route as mentioned by @M. Deinum is the way to go here as I'd like to be able to perform more ad hoc queries.

Comment: You can have a look at the examples here http://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/. It may serve your needs

Comment: I opened [DATAJPA-844](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-844) to request this feature in Spring Data JPA. It seems like it's on their roadmap!

Comment: this answer is now out-of-date

Answer (score 79):

This is now possible with Spring Data. Check out http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example

```
Person person = new Person();                         
person.setLastname("Smith");                          
Example<Person> example = Example.of(person);
List<Person> results = personRepository.findAll(example);
```

Note that this requires very recent 2016 versions

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.1.RELEASE</version>       
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

see https://github.com/paulvi/com.example.spring.findbyexample

Comment: What about a more complex domain. I mean when we have associations how can I use the Example ? Any idea ?

Comment: For a more complex domain, I ended up using QueryDSL with Spring Data JPA. Took me a bit to learn and wrap my head around, but we ended up actually refactoring our code base and eliminating the Example usage completely.

Comment: There's no problem with complex nested domains. Create a domain object with all the associations you need and Example.of(x) will do the job. Sadly I am in trouble with 'between' on date objects.

Comment: can't do between, lessThan greaterThan.... spring teamp are not interested to add this feature... or accept pull request...

Answer (score 28):

Using Spring data's `Specification` interface I was able to approximate the use of query by example.  Here's a `PersonSpec` class which implements `Specification` and requires an "example" person in order to setup the `Predicate` returned by the `Specification`:

```
public class PersonSpec implements Specification<Person> {

  private final Person example;

  public PersonSpec(Person example) {
    this.example = example;
  }

  @Override
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Person> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(example.getLastName())) {
      predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Person_.lastName)), example.getLastName().toLowerCase() + "%"));
    }

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(example.getFirstName())) {
      predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(Person_.firstName)), example.getFirstName().toLowerCase() + "%"));
    }

    if (example.getEmployed() != null) {
      predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(Person_.employed), example.getEmployed()));
    }

    if (example.getDob() != null) {
      predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(Person_.dob), example.getDob()));
    }

    return andTogether(predicates, cb);
  }

  private Predicate andTogether(List<Predicate> predicates, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
    return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
  }
}
```

The repository is simply:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {}
```

Usage example:

```
Person example = new Person();
example.setLastName("James");
example.setEmployed(true);
PersonSpec personSpec = new PersonSpec(example);
List<Person> persons = personRepository.findAll(personSpec);
```

Comment: Good but still I need to create an implementation class for each Query I want to write.

Comment: Where does Person_ come from?

Comment: specification is nice a bit long to write... could be more interesting to be able to search on all field with reflection without writing all this code...

Comment: @PaulVerest `Person_` can be generated with a library like e.g. [hibernate-jpamodelgen](https://hibernate.org/orm/tooling/). Nevertheless, I use instead the Lombok annotation `FieldNameConstants`.