# Spring data JPA query with varying params

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I´m trying to find necessary elements of the table by several parameters like

```
List <Person> findByLastname(String lastname);
```

But what if some of this parameters will be added/deleted in a future? How to make some parameters optional using Spring Data JPA, something like this

```
List <Person> findByOptionalLastnameAndOptionalFirstNameAnd...(String lastname, String firstname,...);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My task was solved by using [querydsl framework](http://www.querydsl.com/). If you use gradle, you will need to add [this](http://bsideup.blogspot.de/2015/04/querydsl-with-gradle-and-idea.html) in **build.gradle**:

```
dependencies {
  compile "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:3.6.3"

  compile "com.mysema.querydsl:querydsl-apt:3.6.3:jpa" // Magic happens here

  compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.5.Final"

  compile 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.187'
}
```

Also possible to use JPA Criteria API, very good example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12199937/5603448) and good tutorial is [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria#JPA_Criteria_API_vs_JPQL_).

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @Id private Long id;    
    String someAttribute;
    String someOtherAttribute;
    ...
}
```

Query itself:

```
//some parameters to your method
    String param1 = "1";
    String paramNull = null;

    CriteriaBuilder qb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery cq = qb.createQuery();
    Root<A> customer = cq.from(A.class);

    //Constructing list of parameters
    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    //Adding predicates in case of parameter not being null
    if (param1 != null) {
        predicates.add(
                qb.equal(customer.get("someAttribute"), param1));
    }
    if (paramNull != null) {
        predicates.add(
                qb.equal(customer.get("someOtherAttribute"), paramNull));
    }
    //query itself
    cq.select(customer)
            .where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));
    //execute query and do something with result
    em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this post is what you are looking for :

[JPA Criteria API Queries](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria)

You can have dynamic conditions, based on inputs by adding multiple predicates to your query.

This reference might also useful [Spring Data JPA Specifications](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#specifications)

Comment: may be you can give example (snippet code) that answer more better :)

Answer (score 2):

Use Query by Example

```
Person person = new Person();                         
person.setLastname("Smith");                          
Example<Person> example = Example.of(person);
List<Person> results = personRepository.findAll(example);
```

Docs  http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example

This is answer of Adam Erstelle to  [Spring Data JPA: Query by Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626825/spring-data-jpa-query-by-example)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use optional parameters and named method resolver of Spring Data, you should create on method for each possibility, that why to make it easier I proposed you to use Specification where you can build a query according to a list of conditions.

If you are not sure that yours parameters will be fixed, then I would use this aproach:

1. Use spring specifications where you can build your queries according some conditions. https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/
2. Create some JUinit tests to be sure yours queries are stable and if somebody add/remove some parameter should modify the JUnit to keep it updated.

If you have some doubt about how to use let me know and i could share you some others examples.

Comment: I edited the question, so the goal more understandable. Cause I have some doubt how to use this specification in my case.

Comment: @BohdanZ I replied you in my response, but i am afraid what you want is not allowed with spring data named method resolver, you should create N-methods with all possible combinations, and you will agree is too complex, then i propose you to use Specifications will be cleaner and easier to understand scale,...

Answer (score -1):

> Yes it is possible but, then you need to make different queries
>   according to given parameters.

**This will be like :**

```
@RequestMapping("find")
public List<Person> findByOptional...(@RequestParam(value = "fName", required = false) String fname,@RequestParam(value = "lName", required = false) String lname) {
    //here you need to check you data for not null and create methods accordingly 
}
```

*But this is not so advisable, if you are passing more optional parameters then need to put more if else conditions.

Comment: This would be the worst way to go. Use Querydsl for a clean solution.

Comment: Thank you @Marc for better solution... I don't have an idea about "Querydsl" I will look after it.

Comment: Check the [Spring data JPA reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) for valuable examples of (look for all occurences of "querydsl").