# Spring Data JPA: Generate dynamic query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have an entity that hold some logic data :

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  private Long id.
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String address;
  ...
}
```

I create my Spring data interface

```
@Repository
public interface CardInventoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Person , Long> {
}
```

My purpose is to create a dynamic query based on the exist values of my entity for example 
if the name is null the query is :

```
select * from Person p  Where p.age=12 AND p.address="adress.."
```

When the address is null the query should be  :

```
select * from Person p  Where p.age=12 AND p.name="ALI"
```

I want to extract data using only the non empty fields ?

is there any solution suing spring data for building dynamic queries ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Spring doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example

> Query by Example (QBE) is a user-friendly querying technique with a
>   simple interface. It allows dynamic query creation and does not
>   require you to write queries that contain field names. In fact, Query
>   by Example does not require you to write queries by using
>   store-specific query languages at all.

**DEFINITION:**
An Example takes a data object (usually the entity object or a sub-type of it) and a specification how to match properties. You can use Query by Example with JPA 
Repositories.

To do so, let your repository interface extend `QueryByExampleExecutor<T>`, for example:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String>, QueryByExampleExecutor<Person> {
}
```

Here are the available methods in `QueryByExampleExecutor` :

```
public interface QueryByExampleExecutor<T> {

  <S extends T> S findOne(Example<S> example);

  <S extends T> Iterable<S> findAll(Example<S> example);

  // … more functionality omitted.
}
```

**USAGES:**

```
Example<Person> example = Example.of(new Person("Jon", "Snow"));
repo.findAll(example);


ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().
    .withMatcher("firstname", endsWith())
    .withMatcher("lastname", startsWith().ignoreCase());

Example<Person> example = Example.of(new Person("Jon", "Snow"), matcher); 
repo.count(example);
```

---

**MORE INFO**

> - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example
> - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/query-by-example
> - [Spring Data JPA: Query by Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626825/spring-data-jpa-query-by-example)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, please take a look at the QueryDSL support for Spring Data. Your use case can be implemented via a Predicate. In a nutshell, you have to create a predicate in which you would pass the non null fields, and then pass that predicate to a findAll method that takes a Predicate as argument. Your repository interface also has to extend QueryDslPredicateExecutor

Answer (score 0):

1. Need to extend repository from `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface EmployeeDAO extends CrudRepository<Employee,Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee>{
}
```

2. Use specification and predicate like below

```
public List<Employee> findByCriteria(String employeeName,String employeeRole){
       return employeeDAO.findAll(new Specification<Employee>() {
           @Override
           public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Employee> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
               List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
               if(employeeName!=null) {
                   predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("employeeName"), "%"+employeeName+"%")));
               }
               if(employeeRole!=null){
                   predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("employeeRole"), employeeRole)));
               }
               return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
           }
       });
   }
```