# Handling a REST API request with many optional query params in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

For the sake of simplicity lets assume I have a `Document` object with seven fields (but imagine that it can have many more). This object looks something like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Document {
    private String fileName;
    private String fileType;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date lastModifiedAt;
    private List<String> modifiers;
    private Long timesModified;
}
```

I want to create an endpoint which can receive any number of `@RequestParam` and returns a `List<Document>` of all the documents which match the given query. For example: return all documents with `fileType == doc`, which were created between `createdAt == 01/01/2021 && createdAt 31/01/2021`, modified  `timesModified == 5` times and `modifiers.contains("Alex")`. The reason for this is that I want to allow the user to query for documents depending on combination of fields the user wants. Originally to handle this we created the endpoint like so:

```
@GetMapping(value = {RestApi.LIST})
public ResponseEntity<List<Document>> getDocuments (@RequestParam Map<String, Object> optionalFilters) {
    List<Document> documents = documentService.getListOfDocuments(optionalFilters);
    if (documents != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(documents, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

The problem with this is that because we use `optionalFilters` as `Map<String, Object>` this requires us to perform a lot of casting in our code and overall makes our code very tedious and cumbersome because we have to iterate through the whole map and create a custom query depending the fields that were passed. In order to try and improve this I created an `OptionalFilters` object:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class OptionalFilters {
    private String fileName;
    private String fileType;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdAt;
    private Date lastModifiedAt;
    private List<String> modifiers;
    private Long timesModified;
}
```

And modified the endpoint to this:

```
@GetMapping(value = {RestApi.LIST})
public ResponseEntity<List<Document>> getDocuments (@Valid OptionalFilters optionalFilters) {
    List<Document> documents = documentService.getListOfDocuments(optionalFilters);
    if (documents != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(documents, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

However, although that this simplifies the way we receive the parameters and extract the values from them, we still need to iterate through all the parameters and create a custom query. Is there some way to elevate and take advantage of `Spring-Data` (or any other solution) so that I don't have to create a custom query depending on each query param that is passed through? I am using `Solr` as the repository if this may be any help.

Comment: If you are using Solr you can create dynamic queries as well.

Comment: https://lucidworks.com/post/spring-data-solr-tutorial-dynamic-queries/

Comment: try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354315/spring-data-jpa-generate-dynamic-query

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez thanks for your reply, this is what I'm currently doing today. The problem with this is that I need to create a custom query depending on the parameters that are sent in which is what I want to avoid. I want to create a single query which I can reuse regardless of the parameters that are sent in.

Comment: @RoieBeck Thanks I'll check it out and update with the result

Answer (score 1):

Using [**Query by Example**](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example) is one the most simple option  but it has its limitations. Excerpt from the above link:

> 5. Limitations
>    Like all things, the Query by Example API has some limitations. For instance:
>
> - Nesting and grouping statements are not supported, for example:
>   (firstName = ?0 and lastName = ?1) or seatNumber = ?2
> - String matching only includes exact, case-insensitive, starts, ends, contains, and regex
>   All types other than String are exact-match only

Query by Example is suitable choice if your filtering is never too complicated. But when restirictions like above hit the fan of your CPU cooler the choice is to use [**Specifications**](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications) to construct queries.

One big difference is also that Using Query by Example you need to explicitly populate the example by its getters and setters. With specification you can make it in a generic way (with Java generics) using just use field names

In your case you could just pass the map to generic method and create filtering by just looping and adding by `and` (note that the link's example has static stuff mostly but it has not to be, you just need field name/criterion -pair to loop it in a generic way)

With specifications you can do anything that can be done with Query by Example and almost anything else also. The overhead to get familiar with specifications might be bigger but the advantage using specifications will be rewarding.

In a nutshell:

Spring `interface Specification` is based on **JPA** `CriteriaQuery` and for each you need only to implement one method:

```
Predicate toPredicate (Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder);
```

Repository interfaces needs just to extend `JpaSpecificationExecutor<YourClass>` When you have a set of predicates, you can - for example -

```
repository.findAll(Specification.where(spec1).and(spec2));
```

It might seem complicated or difficult at start but it is not that at all. The greatest advantage with `Specification` is that you can do almost anything programmatically instead of manipulating JPQL queries or so.