# Using spring data jpa how to execute a native sql query programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am aware about how spring data jpa allows using native queries.

```
@Query(
  value = "SELECT * FROM USERS u WHERE u.status = 1", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Collection<User> findAllActiveUsersNative();
```

Reference - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

But my interest here is, instead of using the SQL with @Query annotation, it is possible to execute the sql query programmatically (for example say how we do while using jdbc) and get result in to a dto or resultset.

I just want to explore above approach for cases where the query might be generated dynamically and may not be know at compile time.

I have seen sof posts, which suggests other approaches like [QueryByExample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354315/spring-data-jpa-generate-dynamic-query) and QueryDSL and i know using JPA Specification also this case can be addressed. And these are great and the right way of addressing dynamic query situation.

**But in this Q, I am interested in knowing if SQL queries can be executed programmatically (not through @Query annotation). If yes, how? (some demo code will help)**

Comment: Look at `EntityManager#createNativeQuery` and `JdbcOperations#query` methods

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always write a repository extension, into which you can inject the `EntityManager`.

Comment: could you add any code examples so i can accept the answer ++1