# How to best use Spring JPA findByXXX where there are multiple combinations?

Tags: spring, jpa

I need to write a service that needs to find an entity using the following combinations:
`firstName`, `lastName`, `phoneNumber`, `emailAddress`

Its becoming a nightmare in my service class and repository to code this. The Permutations are getting out of hand. I still want to use [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) to achieve this but was looking to see if there's  more efficient way to do this?

```
public interface UniversitySearchRepository extends CrudRepository<University, Long> {
    public CcCase findByFirstName(
            @Param("firstName") String firstName);
    
    public CcCase findByLastName(
            @Param("lastName") String lastName);
    
    public CcCase findByEmailAddress(
            @Param("emailAddress") String emailAddress);

    public CcCase findByFirstNameAndLastName(
            @Param("firstName") String firstName, 
            @Param("lastName") String lastName);
    
    public CcCase findByFirstNameAndEmailAddress(
            @Param("firstName") String firstName, 
            @Param("emailAddress") String emailAddress);
    
    public CcCase findByLastNameAndEmailAddress(
            @Param("lastName") String lastName, 
            @Param("emailAddress") String emailAddress);
    ....
```

Comment: You don't have to prefix the parameter by `@Param` if you haven't annotated the method with `@Query`. For your use case, the [specification API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) could be more efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [query-by-example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example): `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository#findAll(Example<S>)`

Related topic: [Spring Data JPA: Query by Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626825/spring-data-jpa-query-by-example)

Comment: Sorry just saw this - Query by Example is exactly what I used. But Marking this as solution for anyone else if its helpful